# BigQuery parameterized queries in Airflow

Tags: parameters, google-bigquery, airflow

I'm trying to create a parameterized query in BigQuery using Airflow. The parameter that will be set in Airflow and will change the value inside the query that will run in BigQuery.

For example, this is my query:

> ```
> select id from table where id = {{params.number_days}}
> ```

The airflow code includes:

> (
> task_id='table',
> use_legacy_sql=False,
> write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
> allow_large_results=True,
> bql=merchant_rank_query,
> destination_dataset_table='prod.table_result',
> params = {'number_days': 1},
> dag=dag)

This does not work, what's the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

For Airflow specifically it looks like this:

```
params = {
    'number_days': 'value_abc'
}

dag = DAG(
    'example_dag',
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    default_args=default_args,
    params=params,
)
```

make sure to set the jinja templating in your sql query.

```
select id from table where id = {{params.number_days}}
```

A medium article not very specific to an operator but generally explaining some tips, also params usage.

***(4) The “params” argument***

https://medium.com/datareply/airflow-lesser-known-tips-tricks-and-best-practises-cf4d4a90f8f

**2nd Option - BigQuery query_params**

If your BigQuery operator supports query_params, you can use something like this:

```
#on top of your code, can be before declaring the dag
dag_exec_date_time = '{{ ts }}'
...
...
...
#then your bigquery operator, if supports query_params

  query_params=[
      {
          "name": "dag_exec_date_time",
          "parameterType": { "type": "STRING" },
          "parameterValue": { "value": dag_exec_date_time}
      }
  ],
```

sql query

```
select cast(@dag_exec_date_time as timestamp) as airflow_timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

To run a [parameterized query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#python) the code looks like:

```
sql = "select id from table where id = @days"
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.query_parameters = [bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('days','INT64',params.number_days)]
query_job = bigquery.Client().query(command=sql, job_config=job_config)
results = query_job.result()
if query_job.errors:
    # log all errors then raise first error
    for e in query_job.errors:
        logging.error(e)
    raise Exception(query_job.errors[0])
```

Bigquery isn't a normal relational database. There is no "plan cache" or other optimisation that make parameterized queries better.  So unless there is some sort of insecure input which could be SQL injection, I recommend not using parameters and putting the values into the SQL because it is so much simpler:

```
sql = f"select id from table where id = {params.number_days}"
query_job = bigquery.Client().query(command=sql)
...
```

Comment: i think you answered out of the context of Apache-Airflow. I believe he wants to leverage the Jinja template that Airflow offers into the parameterized query. `params` is the name of the dict that Airflow passes to each operator.

Comment: @Luis you're correct that this code works outside airflow.  I also use it inside airflow.